# call php var inside JS

Tags: javascript, php

Could you tell me why this is not working ?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$var1 = "hello";
echo $var1;
?>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = <?php echo(json_encode($var1)); ?>;">
HI</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to be able to read the php variable from JS ?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to json_encode a string. Just make sure that there are only escaped quotations inside the string and wrap it in single quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a string. The `'`s needed to added properly around the string.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<?php echo(json_encode($var1)); ?>';"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As `$var1` is `string`, you need to wrap that in quotes.
2. AS `$var1` is string and not `array` or `object`, `json_encode` is not required.

Use quotes around the string(See the marked positions for quotes):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<?php echo($var1) ?>'">
//                                         ^                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite there are many answers, I will give my 2 cents about what I think the OP was thinking:

The basic idea was using json_encode to make the hello string to print `"hello"` instead of `hello`. The problem is actually that it will result in:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "hello";"
```

Which is NOT valid because of double quotes inside of double quotes.

Hence he can keep using `json_encode` if he wants to, as long as he changes the double quotes to single quotes:

```
onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>;'
        ^ <-- single quote       ^----^ <-- double quote here     single there too --> ^
```

This should result in a valid output, which is:

```
onclick='document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "hello";'
```